# Ancient inscription translation (vexillations en visite)

Tags: sens, latin

I am trying to understand an ancient inscription which a French professor has translated in part as:

> ...et a fourni de l'aide pour tout le sejour du gouveneur Rutilius
>   Crispinus et pour les vexillations en visite...

Which I undestand to mean in part: "...and provided help for the entire stay of governor Rutilius Crispinus and for XXX..."

but I do not understand what "vexillations en visite" are. Is a *vexillation* some kind of Roman cavalry unit?

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexillation) to the rescue:

> Une vexillation (latin vexillatio plur. vexillationes), dans l'armée romaine, est un détachement de soldats tiré temporairement d'une unité permanente.